# Как узнать информацию о видеокарте Python

Tags: python, windows

Мне нужно узнать производителя видеокарты через Python, не чего внятного даже в Google не нашёл. Есть догадка что это можно вывести через командную строку, но как определить видеокарту через cmd в интернете так же нет гайдов на эту тему. Помогите пожалуйста!
определять нужно только под Win

Comment: Прям вот ничего не нашли? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103690/get-system-informationcpu-speed-total-ram-graphic-card-model-etc-under-window

Comment: @strawdog, Спасибо! Не искал в английском сегменте так как не сильно знаю английский, ещё раз спасибо, то решение мне полностью подходит!